# How to use .join in this process

Tags: python, join, process, freeze

Hi I am creating this worker generator class, I am getting hangs on terminate I know I need to use a `.join` to close them but I can't figure out how to pass the process name to the `terminate` function. My thought was somehow save it to a global variable, I was thinking a dictionary. Then when it is time to have the workers terminated have `terminate` access that function variable and terminate the applicable process(es) after dropping a poison pill in the message queue

```
class worker_manager:
      i = test_imports()
      #someVarForP 
      #someVarForP2 

      def generate(control_queue, threadName, runNum):
          if threadName == 'one':
              print ("Starting import_1 number %d") % runNum
              p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_queue, runNum))
              #someVarForP = p
              p.start()        
          if threadName == 'two': 
              print ("Starting import_2 number %d") % runNum
              p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_2, args=(control_queue, runNum))
              #someVarForP2 = p2
              p.start()
          if threadName == 'three':    
              p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_queue, runNum))
              print ("Starting import_1 number %d") % runNum
              p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_2, args=(control_queue, runNum))
              print ("Starting import_2 number %d") % runNum
              #someVarForP = p
              #someVarForP2 = p2
              p.start()
              p2.start()

      def terminate(threadName):
           if threadName == 'one':
               #self.someVarForP.join()
           if threadName == 'two':
               #self.someFarForP2.join()
           if threadName == 'three':
               #self.someVarForP.join()
               #self.someVarForP2.join()
```

Any ideas you guys and gals have would be appreciated I am not stuck on any specific way to do this and I am kind of new to python so any suggestions are welcome!

Edit: complete code

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 

class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      def import_1(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_number
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                if alive == 't1kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_number
                   run = False
                   break
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)
                count = count + 1

      def import_2(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_number
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                if alive == 't2kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 2 number %d") % thread_number
                   run = False
                break
                print ("Thread type 2 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)           
                count = count + 1

class worker_manager:
    # ...
    names = {'one': 'import_1', 'two': 'import_2'}
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
    def generate(self, control_queue, threadName, runNum):
        name = self.names[threadName]
        target = i.getattr(name)
        print ("Starting %s number %d") % (name, runNum)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=(control_queue, runNum))
        self.children[threadName] = p
        p.start()
    def terminate(self, threadName):
        self.children[threadName].join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Establish communication queues
    control = multiprocessing.Queue()
    manager = worker_manager()    
    runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
    threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))
    threadName = raw_input("Enter number: ")
    thread_Count = 0

    print ("Starting threads") 

    for i in range(threadNum):
        if threadName == 'three':
            manager.generate(control, 'one', i)
            manager.generate(control, 'two', i)
        manager.generate(control, threadName, i)
        thread_Count = thread_Count + 1              
        if threadName == 'three':
            thread_Count = thread_Count + 1 

    time.sleep(runNum)#let threads do their thing

    print ("Terminating threads")     

    for i in range(thread_Count):
        control.put("t1kill")
        control.put("t2kill")
    if threadName == 'three':
        manager.terminate('one')
        manager.terminate('two')
    else:
        manager.terminate(threadName)
```

Edit only `worker_manager` is the only bit out of this that is actually going to be used. The rest of this is just to develop it just a heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure you understand what `join` does, if you're using it from a function called `terminate`. When you call `join`, all that does is make your parent process wait for the child process to finish. You still need to tell the child process that it needs to finish (e.g., by posting something for it on a queue, or sending it a signal), or you'll end up waiting forever.

Second, the fact that you've left the `self` parameters out of your methods, used an old-style class, created a class attribute where you probably wanted an instance attribute, and started talking about global variables for something that seems perfectly suited for an instance attribute implies that you may have some misunderstandings about classes as well.

But the big problem seems to be that you want to map string names to instance attributes (or some other kind of variable). While you *can* do this, [you almost never want to](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html). Instead of having a separate attribute for each name, just use a single `dict`, with a value for each name. For example:

```
class worker_manager:
    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
    def generate(self, control_queue, threadName, runNum):
        if threadName == 'one':
            print ("Starting import_1 number %d") % runNum
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_queue, runNum))
            self.children[threadName]
            p.start()
        # ...
    def terminate(self, threadName):
        self.children[threadName].join()
```

You can clean this up further by factoring out the common parts of the `if` blocks. For example, you might want a dispatch table. And, while we're at it, let's use more standard names, 4-character indentation instead of random, a new-style class, etc.:

```
class WorkerManager(object):
    # ...
    names = {'one': 'import_1', 'two': 'import_2', 'three': 'import_3'}
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
    def generate(self, control_queue, threadName, runNum):
        name = WorkerManager.names[threadName]
        target = i.getattr(name)
        print ("Starting %s number %d") % (name, runNum)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=(control_queue, runNum))
        self.children[threadName] = p
        p.start()
    def terminate(self, threadName):
        self.children[threadName].join()
```

There's probably a lot more than could be refactored if we could see more of your code, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Yeah I am still learning python, I am playing around teaching myself from web tutorials. 

I tried to run it, but I keep getting this error 

NameError: global name 'names' is not defined

I added a semicolon after your dictionary like I have in my source examples:

names = {'one': 'import_1', 'two': 'import_2', 'three': 'import_3'};

and on the call it is self.names[threadName] THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: First, you should _definitely_ not have semicolons at the end of your lines in Python. If you're teaching yourself by following tutorials that do that… you need to find better tutorials (and maybe you should post the links here so others will know to steer people clear of those tutorials…).

Comment: I am still getting this error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getattr' I added the rest of my code most of it is just to develop the worker_manager class

Comment: @KyleSponable: Your example implies that `i` is some kind of object with methods named `import_1`, etc. My answer assumes the same thing. If `i` is an int instead, it's obviously not going to work. My guess is that your `i` was a global variable, and you've overwritten it somewhere with a `for i in range(10)` or something similar. This is one of many reasons you want to use local variables and instance attributes whenever possible, and good names for everything non-trivial.